# Does it make sense to call an EqualityComparer with an interface as generic parameter

Tags: c#, interface, iequalitycomparer

Let's say I have an this code:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    //  Properties...
}

internal class Realisation : IInterface, IEquatable<IInterface>
{
    //  Properties...

    public bool Equals(IInterface other)
    {
        //  ...
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as IInterface);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

The purpose is to not have duplication/different version of the equality code.

I don't have access to `Realisation` because the code is in a library.
If I have to call the equality comparer of `IInterface`, does it make sense to call `EqualityComparer<IInterface>.Default` here? Will it use the `Equals(IInterface other)` implementation? Or should the equality implementation lies outside of the class? Should I provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<IInterface>`?

**Edit**

- Added `Equals(object obj)` and `GetHashCode()` overrides

Comment: Create a dummy class library with the exact setup and test and find out. This should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it better you put your comparer outside you class , as it satisfy `Single responsibility principle` - class do only one task raher than multiple thing(it should not become super clas) and `(Open Close Principle)Extend your class rather than modifying your class`, which means keep code of equal in seprate class rahter then in your class. (this is my suggestion )

---

One more thing if you have access to class code rather than making use of `IEquatable` , Override base object class method like `Equals & GetHashcode`.

Comment: Yeah I did not mentioned the `Equals` & co override. Added

Comment: @gfache - it just suggestion but if you are going for IEquitable interface implementation do create new class implement it there and do equalizing operation